# How to set initial ScrollView offset?

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

How can I set the ScrollView's initial scrolled offset before my scene appears?

According to the wiki: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/native-cpp/V3.3/d8/d29/classcocos2d_1_1ui_1_1_scroll_view.html

The 2 methods that might do what i am looking for are "**jumpToPercent**" and "**scrollToPercent**" however jump to percent doesn't seem to work at all, and scroll to percent is animated, even when setting the time to 0, which results in the user being able to see a really fast scrolling when the scene starts.

```
scrollView->scrollToPercentHorizontal(scrollToPercent, 0, false);
// scrollView->jumpToPercentHorizontal(scrollToPercent);
this->addChild(scrollView);
```

Comment: I think ui::ScrollView has a bug here. You should call scrollView->jumpToPercentHorizontal(scrollToPercent);  in the scene's onEnter method.

Comment: i just tried it on the onEnter method and it works perfectly. If you would like to add this as an answer ill mark it as correct. By the way, what stuff is usually placed on the "onEnter" method? if i understand correctly, it would be equivalent to the viewWillAppear right?

Answer (score 0):

```
scrollView->setInnerContainerPosition
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one tip for someone using lua, there is a judgement of  `argc` in `lua_cocos2dx_ui_ScrollView_scrollToRight`, and the `argc` must be 2.